# How to use “left” about remaining

Tags: word-usage

Sometimes, I heard or saw sentences with “left”.
For example:

**Be left**

A: How many windows **are left**?

B: There **are** two windows **left**.

I wonder what “left” is.

Is that **the past participle of verb to “leave”**? 
Are the above sentences **passive voice**?

**Left with other verbs**

A: How many tickets do you **have left**?

B: I **have** two tickets **left**.

I also wonder what “left” is here. Is that **adverb**?

**How can we use and put “left”** in a sentence for this meaning?

Should we always put” left” at the end of a sentence?

Would you explain it to me, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per @Pheonix2105's answer, in *some* contexts there might be an implied ***to*** [do something to/with] after the word "left". But I don't see that as particularly relevant to the general case. For example...

> 1: *Tom has 10 apples. He gives 3 to Dick. How many are **left**?*

We neither know nor care whether Tom's 7 apples are "to eat", "to give to Harry", or whatever. All that matters is they're ***remaining*** (not given away, eaten, or otherwise *removed* from the original 10 apples).

In such contexts, ***left*** is simply an "adjectival" use of the past participle of the verb ***to leave***...

> 2: *Tom has 10 apples. Dick takes 3. How many does he **leave**?*

Note that the last sentence there could just as well have been *"How many does this **leave**?"* - it's not really important whether we think of Dick as the "subject" who "leaves" (doesn't take) the leftover apples. If we use ***this***, it's just a [demonstrative pronoun](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/pronouns-demonstrative.htm) meaning *this action which has just been described*.

If you're *interested*, see [here](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/participle-adjectives.html) for some *interesting* information about "Participle Adjectives" (such as "interested" and "interesting" as used earlier in this sentence).

---

Note that there are certain limitations on how adjectival *left = remaining* can be used...

> 3: *Tom sold 3 of his 10 tickets. How many are left unsold?* (either *left* or *unsold* could be omitted)
>    4: *There are 7 left*
>    5: *There are 7 unsold*
>    6: *There are 7 tickets left*
>    7: *There are 7 tickets unsold*
>    8: *There are 7 unsold tickets*
>    9: **There are 7 left tickets* (idiomatically unacceptable)

...where #9 is "unacceptable" even though the basic construction is okay with alternatives which are "synonymous" in context (such as *unsold, remaining*). Because we're more used to adjectival *left* before a noun meaning [*"levo"*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/levo) (on the left, not the right side), we would normally express #9 as...

10: *There are 7 **leftover** tickets*  (or *left-over*)

Comment: Thank you so much FumbleFingers! Your examples and explainations are too useful. For my first example “Be left”. I got it and it’s enlightening. 

 For the second example,  there are left and have. Is left an adjective too? Can they come from long sentences like these?
A: How many tickets do you have to be left?
B I have two tickets which are left.
Could you please check it please?

Comment: @nkm: I can't imagine any possible context for #A *"How many tickets do you have to be left?"*. Including *"to be"* in such a construction implies *"**which are and always were intended** to be unsold"* - which makes no real-world sense to me, since the tickets could only be described as *left [over], unsold* if you'd tried to sell them but failed. And native speakers would almost never include *"which are"* in constructions like your example #B. The reason for this is subtle, but I'll try to explain...

Comment: If I say *"I have 2 tickets which are cheap"*, it might be that I *only* have 2 tickets (and they are both cheap), or that I have many other (more expensive) tickets, but only 2 cheap ones. But *left* is different, in that by definition, if I still have them they must be *left [over]*, and also by definition I can't still *"have"* any other tickets which are *not* left/remaining. Repetition and tautology are not inherently incorrect in English, but in a case like your example #B there, we simply wouldn't do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot again! I really appreciate your help. I've learned a lot from your examples and explaination. I think I understand well how to use "left" now. Have a nice day!:)

Answer (score 4):

A: How many windows are left(to clean)?

B: There are two windows left (to clean).

A: How many tickets do you have left(to sell)?

B: I have two tickets left (to sell).

It all depends on the context it is said in, if we were cleaning windows while I said "How many windows are left" to you, you would probably guess I am asking how many more windows we have to clean :)

Comment: I understand more about "left" and your explaination is very useful but I still wonder and don't understand what left is in those cases. Is it past participle or adverb or something else? However, Thank you very much Pheonix2105!